# how to change object's B color when object A is in range? 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance, object-detection

I have an enemy AI object that randomly patrols a top down 2d maze(object B) and within this maze are tiles(multiple objects of A). I'm having trouble figuring out a way to change the color of only 1 tile that is within close distance to the enemy object B. Here is my code:

public Transform blocks;

```
 private void Update()
 {
     blocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Breakable_Block").transform;

     if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, blocks.position) < 10)
     {
         blocks.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
     }


 }
```

What I'm trying to do with my project is to have an invisible enemy object patrol randomly in the maze and when it comes in contact or range of 1 tile the tile changes color. When the enemy moves away the tile changes back to it's regular color.The reason why I'm using distance instead of collision is because I cannot have the enemy object crash and get stuck with the tiles themselves.

[image: Enemy is sky-blue and tiles are purple.]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
I mistakenly read `FindGameObjectWithTag` as `FindGameObjectsWithTag`. The first returns a single GameObject, the second returns an array of GameObjects. So the next paragraph is incorrect. If there are going to be multiple "Breakable_Block" objects I'd still lean towards using Triggers. If there is only ever a single "Breakable_Block", then a Vector2.Distance could be the more appropriate.

*So, a quick note, `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Breakable_Block")` will return an array of GameObjects, so the code example you've given won't be able to find the distance from your player to the whole array. You'd need to find the distance to the indivual objects. Which involves more code. This is the reason I think using the tools available in Unity might be simply easier.*

So, I'd implement it this way:

- Add a [CircleCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CircleCollider2D.html) to your enemy (Object B). Mark it as a
  `Trigger`.
- Add a [BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) to your blocks ( assuming they're
  rectangular ).
- Implement [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html), and [OnTriggerExit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerExit2D.html) to change
  your material properties.

Here's is a quick code example you could place on your Enemy (Object B).

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
  void OnTriggerEnter2D ( Collider2D other )
  {
    other.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
  }

  void OnTriggerExit2D ( Collider2D other )
  {
    other.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Breakable_Block") will return an array of GameObjects"* No really. `FindGameObjectWithTag` will return one object. `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns array. Notice the 's' in the Object. Since OP want's to return objects "closer" not objects "colliding" I think that the `Vector2.Distance` use by OP is more appropriate than the `OnTriggerXXX` in your answer.

Comment: @Programmer MY mistake entirely, I honestly though I saw an "s" in there, as in `FindGameObjectsWithTag`. I'll edit this, as my initial statement is completely wrong.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure if that was a misread so I had to comment

Comment: @Programmer the other point that tripped me up is his use of the phrase "I'm having trouble figuring out a way to change any tiles that is within close distance to the enemy object B". So I'm not actually entirely sure the OP DOESN'T want to find ALL tiles within range. As the OP has indicated it's a maze, we should assume there are going to be multiple tiles?

Comment: Yes, it's a maze but I think that matters. Even in the title, it says "object is in range". If OP said he wants to change color when they touch with other objects then you can `OnTriggerXXX`.Maybe you're right. I think that OP should clarify what's wrong with the current code. OP has not escribe the issue but only said what he wants to do.

Comment: Hello Milan and Programmer, thank you for your feedback! I'm sorry I was too vague with my question. As Milan stated I am indeed trying to only change 1 tile. What I'm trying to do with my project is to have an invisible enemy object patrol randomly in the maze and when it comes in contact or range of 1 tile the tile changes color. When the enemy moves away the tile changes back to it's regular color. I can't find an example at the moment but I will edit my question and add in a screenshot of my game.

Comment: @Programmer The reason why I'm using distance instead of collision is because I cannot have the enemy object crash and get stuck with the tiles themselves.

Comment: @user1656528 In that, I'd still use a BoxCollider2D, with Trigger set on the colliders, as the "simplest" way of triggering a colour change. There's would be a total of 256 colliders (as per your diagram), which won't be an issue on any platform. A BoxCollider2D won't have your enemy "crash" into it, if the collider is set as a Trigger. I think that's where you're getting stuck. I also said "simplest", not "most efficient", but in this case I think you'd be hard pressed to even measure a difference in performance.

Comment: @Milan  Thank you for your help! It worked perfectly.